# What does $\mathbb{E}_{\mu \sim z} [p(z)]$ stand for?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, machine-learning

We are given the normal density $$p(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^d \det(\Sigma)}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (x- \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\right),$$ where we consider the positive definite matrix $\Sigma$ to be fixed.

I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}_{\mu \sim z} [G_{z}G_z^T]$ to find the Fisher kernel, where
$$
G_x
= \frac{d}{d \mu} \log(p(x)) 
= \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu) \log(p(x)).
$$
What does $\mathbb{E}_{\mu \sim z}$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that notation in machine learning papers to denote the expectation of $\mu$ under the distribution $z$. See for example equation (6) in: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf or page 2 here: https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf

EDIT: 
That means that $z$ is a valid distribution for $\mu$.

Comment: How is $z$ a random variable? Isn't it just an argument of a function?

Comment: So in this case $\mathbb E_{\mu \sim z}[p(z)] = \int p(z) \, \text{d}\mu(z)$?

Comment: @ViktorStein yes